# "This is not a typewriter" error when trying to install Lubuntu

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu

I am trying to install Lubuntu on a MSI 135DX notebook

specs: 1GB RAM, 250GB HDD, Atom n455 CPU, 10" LED WSVGA screen.

I have tried Lubuntu, Linux lite and Mint and they all have the same problem: install starts and asks for language. I get a flashing logo than after a while in Lubuntu

```
this is not a typewriter
```

scrolls down the page.

I will be upgrading RAM to 2GB when it arrives.

What else should I try?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_a_typewriter